# Unrecognized selector sent to instance - Application crashes only on Release

Tags: ios, react-native

**NOTE** This is more of an iOS troubleshooting question not a React Native one. So even if you're an iOS dev and not specifically into React Native, please please read further. Your help will be greatly appreciated :)

I am building a React Native app with the Agora SDK using the react native wrapper from https://github.com/syanbo/react-native-agora

I have a weird issue when launching a new Video call, I get the following error:

```
2019-01-23 16:20:18.512762+0530 PwcApp[786:355367] Exception '-[AgoraRtcEngineKit setClientRole:withKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1072a7b80' was thrown while invoking init on target Agora with params (
        {
        appid = c617eddc6ceb4782adb509aa91b17580;
        channelProfile = 1;
        clientRole = 1;
        swapWidthAndHeight = 1;
        videoProfile = 40;
    }
)
callstack: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001beb37f10 <redacted> + 252
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001bdd05a40 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001bea4f154 <redacted> + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001beb3d810 <redacted> + 1412
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001beb3f4bc _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    5   PwcApp                              0x00000001055f48f4 -[RCTAgora init:] + 1200
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001beb3f660 <redacted> + 144
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001bea1b980 <redacted> + 292
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001bea1c564 <redacted> + 60
    9   PwcApp                              0x00000001048fa30c -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 492
    10  PwcApp                              0x000000010493fa60 _ZN8facebook5reactL11invokeInnerEP9RCTBridgeP13RCTModuleDatajRKN5folly7dynamicE + 248
    11  PwcApp                              0x000000010493f7bc ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke + 88
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106e87840 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106e88de4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106e96a94 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1360
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001beac61bc <redacted> + 12
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001beac1084 <redacted> + 1964
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001beac05b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001c0d34584 GSEventRunModal + 100
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00000001eb507558 UIApplicationMain + 212
    20  PwcApp                              0x0000000104787240 main + 124
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001be580b94 <redacted> + 4
)
```

This error happens only on a **Release** build. Debug runs completely fine. From all that I could gather this far I figured that there are a couple common culprits to this. Essentially I tried to eliminate as much difference between Release and Debug as possible. What I have tried so far:

1. Set `Strip debug symbols on copy` to NO on Release (set it same as debug).
2. Set `Dead code stripping` to NO on Release (set it same as debug).
3. Set `Build Active Architecture only` to NO on Release (set it same as debug).
4. Set `Optimization level` to NONE [-O0] (set it same as debug).

None of the above seems to solve the problem. So my question mostly now is how do I proceed in terms of troubleshooting? Is there any other setting that differs between the Debug/Release build that I could try?

Comment: try clean build folder

Comment: Tried that earlier, and just gave it another shot. No luck :(

Comment: It seems that `setClientRole:withKey:` is called here: https://github.com/syanbo/react-native-agora/blob/2c0285354697a814c3bbd41865f48f33c8839cb1/ios/RCTAgora/RCTAgora.m#L63. It might be a good idea to set a breakpoint there in Xcode and work from there. See what the value of `self.rtcEngine` is etc.

Comment: This is what I get when I put in a breakpoint at the specified line number: https://imgur.com/a/Rrb0eix